# HTML Search for spots based on address/city

Tags: javascript, html, search, popup

I'm trying to search for a solution for my website that would let the user input their city and it would give them data based on that (like custom html with my own content, points of interests, etc). For example if they write "Stockholm" to a search box it would give a popup or similar to output the data related to that city.

Is there a ready solution for this in open source?

Thanks for all advice related to this.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

**The Easy-ish Way**  If you store City names with your points-of-interest data, would be just to build a lookup, and match on those city names.

**The Better Way**

1. Store the lat/long of all of your points-of-interest (in database or
   in search engine).
2. Use an external geocoding API like [Google
   Maps](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&address=stockholm), or [OpenStreetMap](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?place_id=142232280) to power a typeahead control.
3. Once the user has selected a typeahead suggestion, capture either the
   bounding box (Google), or if you want, the entire polygon
   (OpenStreetMap) from the geocoding API and use that to search for
   your POI within the boundary.

Try [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) (postgres database add-on), or [Solr](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spatial+Search) (search engine) for your location filtering.

---

If you're using Google Maps to get a bounding-box, you don't need any particularly fancy GIS tooling in the back-end.  Just query your database for all points-of-interest where:

`latitude BETWEEN <SW_lat> AND <NE_lat> AND longitude BETWEEN <NE_long> AND <SW_long>`

*Be aware that bounding boxes are approximations for true city borders, and that you'll have boundary conditions at the International Date Line and Poles ... but hopefully you don't have any POI there to worry about.*

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the goal, in my opinion you may use ElasticSearch for quick autocomplete to get user input and validate it, then use the refined input to do geocoding using whatever geocoding engine you have.

If you are looking for something really quick, just go with google free-tier geocoding service endpoint.